# PostgreSQL DB error could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: postgresql, linux, memory

We have PostgreSQL `9.2` on AWS with `16G` memory (no swap) we have following kernel setting

```
kernel.shmall = 6802050
kernel.shmmax = 13930597974
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
```

our DB is very small because all it does just store some key value for apache/php to run application but we have very high volume traffic on web servers, recently we notice kernel start killing postgresql with `OOM` error so we have tried following option

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
```

Notes: This is what i was try to do https://serverfault.com/questions/141988/avoid-linux-out-of-memory-application-teardown

but when i try to start postgresql i got following error

```
Sep 22 13:18:25 db.world.com postgres[874]: [1-1] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
Sep 22 13:18:25 db.world.com postgres[874]: [1-2] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=9210265600, 03600).
Sep 22 13:18:25 db.world.com postgres[874]: [1-3] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory or swap space, or exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.  To reduce the request size (currently 9210265600 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
Sep 22 13:18:25 db.world.com postgres[874]: [1-4]    The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
```

so i tried to reduce `shared_buffer` to `6GB` and start postgresql and it came up successful but as soon as load start it start throwing `out of memory` error again. any suggestion

Comment: Suggestions? Reduce `shared_buffer` some more -- Postgres still wants about 8.5 GB or memory, according to the error message. If as you say your database is small, do you really need 6 GB buffers? I presume, your Apache and PHP run on the same machine too?

Comment: we have front end 6 apache web server behind `ELB` load-balancer, so DB machine is dedicated for postgres, problem is one day we ran out of connection so we increased `max_connection=8192`  and it required more `share_buffer`

Comment: max_connection=8192 is crazy high. If you need more than several hundred connection, please use some pooling software in front.

Comment: i read about `pgbouncer` but we have no past experience, do you know how it work and make it effective?

Comment: That deserves another question. Look carefully at https://pgbouncer.github.io/ and then come back.

Comment: Did you try with other version. `9.2` is obsolete as of September 2017 when you posted your question so while stick with it?